# Datagrid и MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

Добрый день всем. Появился такой вопрос. В WinForm C# добавил datagridview, выбрал источник данных - БД. Теперь при запуске формы Datagrid автоматически заполняется содержимым базы. Но как сделать так, что бы можно было изменять данные в Datagrid, и они сохранялись в базу? Заранее спасибо

Comment: почитайте вот [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fbk67b6z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [тут](http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/s/e025ff60a1463236ebb166c4a9fb51e8/topic-301322.html) и [здесь](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/db/4289935.flat)

Comment: Спасибо, все решилось добавлением одной строчки

ИмятаблицыTableAdapter.Update(имябазыDataSet);